# Remove user login session in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.4

I want to have an option in administrator panel for killing a user session,

I have a log monitor for all users sessions, and I have session id of each user.

How can I delete session for a user in laravel with session id ?

`forget()` not work with session id :

```
$request->session()->forget($session);
```

`$session` is the user session id which I store in database before with `$request->session()->getId()` .

Comment: What session driver do you use?

Comment: @Kyslik sessions stored in files

Comment: I doubt its possible with vanilla Laravel, maybe if you used redis driver. You will need to hack...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$request->session()->flush();
```

Comment: Are you sure I can remove just one session with this method ?

Comment: The forget method will remove a piece of data from the session. If you would like to remove all data from the session, you may use the flush method:

$request->session()->forget('key');

$request->session()->flush();

Answer (score 1):

You may use `database` instead of `file` [session](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#driver-prerequisites), and then delete user session this way (which can also be used in api routes):

```
$user_id = '123';
DB::table('sessions')
    ->whereUserId($user_id)
    ->delete();
```

In my personal case, I get the user id from api route request:

```
$user_id = $request->user()->id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use method destroy to delete a session with session id.

```
destroy($sessionId);
```

You can read more here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#adding-custom-session-drivers